# Composer: Can't write to cache file

Tags: caching, composer-php, file-permissions, symfony

I am new to Symfony and Composer.

I recently installed Symfony 3 with [the installer](http://symfony.com/download.) (on Linux) just as explained.
Afterwards I also [installed Composer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/composer.html).

When I try to run [an update with Composer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#updating-symfony-applications) it gives errors like:

```
post-update-cmd: Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to write cache  
file "/home/dev/var/bootstrap.php.cache".' in 
/home/dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:236
```

and

```
[RuntimeException]                            
Unable to write in the cache directory (/home/dev/var/cache/dev)  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the  
post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
[RuntimeException]            
Unable to write in the cache directory (/home/dev/var/cache/dev) 

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the 
post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
[RuntimeException]                                     
An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

I found some issues but they were old and seem to have a specific reason. I just cannot figure out what is going wrong.

I set the owner/group of `/var` to `www-data` which is the Apache 2 user. I set the write permissions for the group. Even tried 777 on `/var/cache` and `bootstrap.php.cache`. 
It won't help.

When I delete the `cache-dir` it is created normally by Symfony. `/var/cache/dev` and `/prod` are also created and loaded with dirs and files.
I can't find `bootstrap.php.cache` anymore now.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Centos Linux, by default SELinux (/etc/sysconfig/selinux) is set to "enforcing" mode. This will prevent apache user or httpd process from writing to Symfony cache and log paths. Most people take the easy way out by setting to "permissive" mode and rebooting the OS.

The right approach is to leave SELinux in "enforcing" mode and use policycoreutils-python to change some permissioning. These instructions assumes you have used setfacl as per Symfony2 docs.

```
sudo yum install policycoreutils-python
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content true
sudo setsebool allow_httpd_anon_write true
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
sudo restorecon -rv /var/www
```